# Brand-new 32GB flash drive unmounts randomly, in an matter of minutes

Tags: usb, mount, cron, storage

I purchased a new flash drive, and mounted it to my pi in two steps:

Step one: Get the drive ID:

*`ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`*

Result:

```
    total 0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep 22 22:17 04DC-AE7F -> ../../mmcblk0p5
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 25 10:56 332B-0D50 -> ../../sdo1
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec 31  1969 40addd1d-dbe4-44ae-8536-ebc916723a4e -> ../../mmcblk0p3
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec 31  1969 AF6A-E2AB -> ../../mmcblk0p1
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep 22 22:17 b5206b05-d30d-4e01-add1-0804705a747b -> ../../mmcblk0p6
```

Step two: Mount the drive to a folder.

*`sudo mount /dev/sd*1 ~/Media/usb1 -o uid=pi,gid=pi`*

Step three: Check to see if the Flash Drive is mounted:

*`for i in $(find ~/Media/usb1/ -maxdepth 1 -type d) ; do echo -n $i": " ; ( find $i -type f | wc -l ); done`*

Result:

```
    /home/pi/Media/usb1/: 1241
    /home/pi/Media/usb1/TestA: 0
    /home/pi/Media/usb1/Storage: 0
    /home/pi/Media/usb1/Scripts: 639
    /home/pi/Media/usb1/Timestamp: 599
```

And everything's fine.

I had to use an asterisk because the letter kept changing, and I mounted it to a folder in my userspace because if it's mounted to `/root/media` cron won't work and cd gives me an error: `-bash: cd: /root/media: Permission denied`

And functionally, this has no problems: I can read, write, download files, etc. There's just the small problem of the flash drive randomly un-mounting, which it does about every 5 minutes or so. I tried using cron as a temporary workaround:

`* * * * * sudo mount /dev/sd*1 ~/Media/usb1 -o uid=pi,gid=p`

but that didn't work. Can anyone assist me?

Comment: would help to include the OS details -  `cat /etc/os-release`. 
does this happen with only this flash drive or every drive (smaller / larger capacity) you have tried ?
can you try plugging it into another USB slot and verify the behavior is same ?

Comment: found a few of threads you might want to checkout [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/897), [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=118891) and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=62546)

Comment: Here: `PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums" BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"`

Comment: raspbian wheezy is quite old, try flashing the newer [`jessie`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-jessie-is-here/) on another card and see if the problem persists. jessie is supposed to support PI 1/2/3 so should work on yours too.

Comment: Got it. The thing is, it will be a week or two before I can order a new flash drive. Is there a temporary software workaround I can use? Why didn't the `cron` job work?

Comment: Sorry but I am not aware any workarounds. As for the cron job, i believe the syntax of the job entry could be wrong. All errors will be logged in `/var/log/syslog`. Running `tail /var/log/syslog` should provide some insight. [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) is the official docs on how to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cron` will achieve nothing good, since unmounting will keep happening, and at some point it will collide with disk write operation and damage the file system.

Though is is unlikely, what you observe looks like a power problem, try setting `max_usb_current=1` in `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting. And make sure you have a decent power supply.

Comment: It WORKED! I also ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` for good measure.

Comment: @Rich Glad to hear it! You sure have one power-hungry flash drive ;)